# Facebook android integration image sharing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook sdk library for integrating facebook in my andriod app. its conecting successfully and posting message correctly but when i try to image with the message it gives error in responce.

```
String response = mFacebook.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();            
            parameters.putString("message", "abc"); 
            parameters.putString("picture", "http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?um=1&hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=cP0_FJwyf8mtEM:&imgrefurl=http://valeriaalves.com/casa/js/goog-pictures&docid=cBJZIsB_ap6C0M&imgurl=http://valeriaalves.com/casa/js/goog-pictures-753.jpg&w=400&h=282&ei=QCojUb-hA5SQ4gSwpYGYDg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:76&iact=rc&dur=463&sig=115747166598885772962&page=1&tbnh=177&tbnw=247&start=0&ndsp=15&tx=107&ty=61"); 
            response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

kindly help me in solving the issue.

Comment: i have tested many urls its giving errors like {"error":{"message":"(#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed","type":"OAuthException","code":368}}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
params.putString("message","Photo upload test");
params.putByteArray("picture", photo);  // Where photo is byte[]
```

and change me/feed with **me/photos**